# SATA HDD stuttering on reads (LED on)

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata

I hope I can get some new ideas to solve the issue. What I have:

- AMD Phenom II X4 905e Box, Sockel AM3
- Gigabyte GA-MA790XTA-UD4, AMD 790X, AM3 ATX
- WD Caviar GreenPower 1,5TB SATA II
- 4GB Kit OCZ DDR3 PC3-10666 Platinum Low-Voltage CL7
- HIS HD 4670 iSilence4 DDR3 1024MB Native HDMI Dual-DVI, PCI-Express

Behavior: Everything works normally excepting the HDD accesses. The drive seems to get stuck in reading data (LED drive by mainboard is on for a while) then recovers and goes on. There is a delay of more than 30s sometimes. Often it is a matter of 5-10s. This does not seem related to the workload of the disk.

What I tried so far:

- Use different SATA port: I switched from the SATA3 to SATA2 then the SATA driven by the CPU, no difference.
- Turned AHCI off, drove the SATA in IDE mode, same behavior, now I felt like the HDD has problems
- Deactivated energy saving settings (BeQuiet, ...), disabled 3 cores (msconfig) supposing some race condition or trouble with changing freqs, same trouble
- With Windows7 Professional 64Bit, I installed the hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B976418&x=8&y=9 with no success. The problem description matches what I experienced, so I felt lucky but was quite in a sad mood after being deceived.
- Burned the DLG 5.04f DataLifeGuard CD from WD to check the drive. All tests passed, to my surprise!
- Installed an Ubuntu on the same drive i386 flavour. Drive still in IDE mode, exactly the same behavior. So the OS does not matter.

What I did not try yet:

- http://www.gigabyte.eu/Support/Motherboard/BIOS_Model.aspx?ProductID=3263 I have a F2 BIOS and there is a F3a Beta, did someone have similar issues that were solved by this update? It is a beta so I fear upgrading a bit and I could find no release notes at all on the net, not really serious work maybe they had issues translating from Chinese???
- Using another HDD drive

Does someone have other hints or a similar issue? Maybe it is neither the HDD nor the Mainboard/BIOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, this is a faulty HDD - the data reads are succeeding after several tries which is why you aren't getting errors.

I would try another HDD drive - or try that drive in another machine - to try and determine if it is faulty or not. I wouldn't trust it with data you need until you've established for sure that it is not the drive.

Comment: I am currently backing up everything and will report result of the try...

Comment: It is definitively the drive. I built it into another computer same behaviour. Reinstalled Win7 after a while surfing, or during data copy (3GB) the drive stuttered again. Driven in IDE mode, I tend to say that the situation is even worse. RMA...