# I can see a HD but im not able to mount it

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, mount, performance

I think some hard disk files are damaged because windows is slow at loading...Now i'm using ubuntu and even if I can see the disk i cannot mount it..... how i can fix this thing?

thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to mount it in Ubuntu? How are you planning to fix it when you have mounted it from there? Try running CheckDisk as suggested by jrc03c and also check my answer about tools to check your hard drive: http://superuser.com/questions/157266/when-to-stop-using-a-hard-drive/157276#157276

Answer (score 1):

Slowness in Windows can be caused by a large number of things.  Malware, hardware issues, fragmentation, etc.  Let's tackle them one-by-one:

- Have you tried running CheckDisk from Windows?  CheckDisk will check your hard drive for errors and (via certain flags) will try to fix them.  Click on the Start menu, choose "Run...", and enter:

  `chkdsk /F /R`

  Hit ENTER.  It'll tell you that the hard drive is currently in use, and will ask you if you want to run the command at the next boot, and you say yes.  Then reboot.

  The scan takes a little while.  If it doesn't fix the problem(s), open your hard drive with GParted in an Ubuntu LiveCD (GParted is already installed in the LiveCD) and see if it gives you any errors.
- Have you removed all malware?  I'd recommend starting with Panda Antivirus or Microsoft Security Essentials.
- Have you defragged your hard drive lately?
- You might download [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/builds) to help clean out crap / temporary files and clean up the registry (by the way, cleaning the registry doesn't always help; lots of people are on the fence about its usefulness).
- Use `msconfig` to turn off unwanted startup items and services (CCleaner can do this, too).

This list isn't comprehensive.  Anyone else got any good ideas?  If none of these things work and Windows is still slow, then you might just have to purchase a new hard drive.

Comment: Malware isn't going to cause Ubuntu to not mount a filesystem - filesystem errors, however, will.

Comment: Right, I just wanted to make sure we had all the bases covered and had narrowed down the problem.  And he didn't specify which version of Ubuntu he was using; perhaps older versions don't automatically mount disks.  It just seemed to me that it would be preferable to narrow down the problem in light of the sparse details Alex provided.

Answer (score 1):

See these instructions to force a mount in Ubuntu

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/