# Why can't I repair my Windows XP installation? Partitioned [unknown]

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, repair, reinstall, chkdsk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME (0x000000ED) on my Windows XP DELL laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/177440/how-to-fix-unmountable-boot-volume-0x000000ed-on-my-windows-xp-dell-laptop)

I have a computer that I need to do a installation repair on. It's running a SATA drive and have tried everything:

- `fixboot`
- `fixmbr`
- slipstream XP using `nlite` to include the SATA drivers
- `chkdsk /r` to try to fix any disk errors (just freezes @ 50%)

The problem with the computer is winxp won't boot, not even in safemode. It just restarts. I froze the error and got:

> UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME
>   stop: 0x000000ED (0x8a635590,0xc0000009c,0x00000000,0x00000000)

When I go to try to do the repair using the Windows XP CD, I click enter to view partitions, then I am supposed to see an option to choose 'R' for repair which will reinstall the Windows installation but keep documents and settings and applications. But no option is available and the partition just says

> Partitioned [unknown]

Can anyone give me some advice or tips? I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have partition damage, I would suggest using [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to attempt repair of the partition(s). Do plenty of reading before you use the software.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a sata disk, then you'll need a floppy disk with the controller driver on it.  XP didn't know about sata.  When you boot with CD you'll see an option to press F6( I think) to load a driver to access storage.  Once you do that, it should recognize the disk

Comment: I think I did that by creating a slipsteam (as I don't have a floppy drive) which included the SATA 32bit drivers from ASUS the motherboard manufacturer. But, that still didn't work. Maybe i did it wrong.