# How do I troubleshoot boot freezes and UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, partitioning, bsod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME (0x000000ED) on my Windows XP DELL laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/177440/how-to-fix-unmountable-boot-volume-0x000000ed-on-my-windows-xp-dell-laptop)
>   [How do I fix “Unmountable Boot Volume”?](https://superuser.com/questions/286007/how-do-i-fix-unmountable-boot-volume)

I have my computer partitioned into 2 separate partitions. One for Vista and the other for Windows 7. This has never been a problem before. I have only used Windows 7 for a long time now and because I run various things on this desktop I have it running 24/7 and I give it a break every few days or so.

It was running fine when I turned it off for an hour or so then when I turned it back on I got a bunch of errors and nothing would respond on my desktop after logging on. I had to hard reboot it. After I restarted my computer would get stuck at the loading screen. I tried safe mode, it froze, I tried Repair Computer, it froze.

I tried the vista partition and I got blue screened with the following error. `UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME`

Nothing works. Can someone please tell me what happened and possible solutions?

Comment: **Related:** [When you restart your computer or upgrade to Windows XP, you receive the "STOP 0x000000ED UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME" error message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297185)

Comment: **Related:** [Trouble with UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME 0x000000ED](http://superuser.com/questions/177440/trouble-with-unmountable-boot-volume-0x000000ed)

Comment: What makes you 99% sure? Your hard drive might be just fine, **throwing it away just because of a BSOD would be a shame**. [Verification can spare you money](http://superuser.com/questions/349267/how-do-i-troubleshoot-boot-freezes-and-unmountable-boot-volume/349268#349268), you stated that you didn't have funds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you boot from another disc, while having this drive in the system - it might be accessible, it might not. What I would recommend doing is getting a bootable linux system - check out [debian live](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/release/current-live/i386/iso-hybrid/). You can install it on an USB pendrive and boot from it. Once inside, you would need a pair of tools like **smartmontools** (smartctl) and **ntfs-3g**. The first one will give you an overview of the drives **SMART** data, that is a good indicator of its health, while the second one will enable you to mount your **NTFS** partition. [As suggested by Tom](https://superuser.com/questions/349267/how-do-i-troubleshoot-boot-freezes-and-unmountable-boot-volume/349268#349268) - you will need a **chkdsk /F /R** run over the drive/filesystem before mounting. All of this assumes some basic Linux literacy.

Answer (score 2):

You can make or download system repair discs which will let you do basic repairs from a windows 7 system.

In this sort of situation, i'd start by booting up a linux livecd (i use some ubuntu varient, usually xubuntu) and

1. force mount the partitions in question in linux, and attempt data recovery
2. install [gsmartctrl](http://gsmartcontrol.berlios.de/home/index.php/Downloads) in the livecd and run smart tests. Compare values against [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes)
3. attempt to do a repair of the install off a [system repair disc](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-SG/windows7/Create-a-system-repair-disc) - you could get a friend to make one. You might also considering getting a copy of the windows 7 installer from a friend and converting it into a [universal install disc](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/85813-windows-7-universal-installation-disc-create.html) using the keys from your system

By this point you should

- have your data copied out
- know with a good level of certainty if your drive is ACTUALLY damaged
- be able to fix a drive with logical but not physical corruption

Answer (score 1):

***Do not assume that a HDD is bad*, just because you see a blue screen.**

Without making any assumptions, let's diagnose whether the possible causes exist:

1. Check if the disk is still properly working, [check SMART table and do an error scan](https://superuser.com/questions/157266/when-to-stop-using-a-hard-drive-what-rules-software-apply/157276#157276). Back-up if not...
2. Try to run `chkdsk /r` on the partition(s) and check if the I/O cables are connected properly.
3. Do a [memory test](http://www.memtest.org/), ensure that there are no errors or else replace it.
4. As a last resort, back-up your data then do a format and reinstall...

Try an installation medium and hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, an alternative could be [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) with which you can do all of the above steps as they are all provided by Hiren's Boot CD...

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I don't have the installation medium which is the problem.

Comment: The problem is I don't have access to an installation medium so I cannot access a command prompt window. Also, how would I go about running an error scan and a "check SMART table" if I cannot access either partition?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the funds or the means to get a new disk... is there any other way you can think of?

Comment: Well, another option is to get [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/).

Comment: Select W7 from your dual boot menu and keep hitting F8 for a list of options. One of them should be "Repair your computer" - you can access a command prompt from there. Run **chkdsk /F /R** on the according volume. It might take quite a bit, depending on the drives condition and overall drive size. Once complete - try booting. However, this is not a stable solution - but it might help you to recover a more or less operational state. The real problem is the drive going bad.. You probably have a lot of reallocated sectors and heaps of pending to be reallocated. Only simple cases are auto handled

Comment: @XXL: Read the question, your comment makes no sense.

Comment: @Tom Wijsman: you are actually right, my bad. I must have overlooked OPs post - he did say that he already tried the "repair" option and it froze