# Unmountable Boot Volume

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME (0x000000ED) on my Windows XP DELL laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/177440/how-to-fix-unmountable-boot-volume-0x000000ed-on-my-windows-xp-dell-laptop)

I have a Toshiba Satellite `L40`. Two days ago, I turned it off by holding the power button and the next day it would not start at all. There is a blue screen with an error : `UNMOUNTABLE BOOT VOLUME`. I searched all over the net for a solution and did everything I could think of such as using the Windows 7 install disk and trying to repair with the command prompt (check `c: /r, bootfix` etc.). It runs the check saying there are no errors. However, when I restart I get the blue screen again. Can someone please give me some new solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the Win7 Repair install like posted [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html)? It works fine for me a couple of times, I even can recreate a missing bootloader and \BOOT folder after an file image restore.