# Windows unrecoverable error wouldn't come out of Hibernate

Tags: windows-7, windows, hibernate

*Out of curiosity...*

I was in a rush:

1. I put my laptop into `Hibernate` (I don't keep a battery in it btw)
2. Leaned it against a box in the laundry room
3. Smooth tile floor means bottom of laptop slide out and laptop feel flat against floor, not super hard, but it wasn't carpeting so..
4. Next time I booted my laptop, I received this error for the first time ever:

(not an exact quote)

> Windows experienced an unrecoverable error and cannot come out of `Hibernate`.  Windows is restarting now

After that, my laptop seemed to operate flawlessly.

**What do you think happened?  Jarred the electronics?  I'm guessing an error like this would result of some sort of hard drive trauma, but fortunately, I have discovered none so far.**

I scheduled `Error-checking` for next restart.

**UPDATE 1/11/11**

I ran `CHKDSK` and fortunately my hard drive came away from the incident unscathed!  Here is part of the log for those interested:

```
File verification completed.
  184 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.
  2 EA records processed.
  66 reparse records processed.

Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.
  117113849 KB total disk space.
  101171452 KB in 262060 files.
    150136 KB in 86722 indexes.
          0 KB in bad sectors.
     514945 KB in use by the system.
      65536 KB occupied by the log file.
   15277316 KB available on disk.
```

Comment: Most likely to be problems with your hard drive, try to scan for erorrs and check your S.M.A.R.T. information. [This answer](http://superuser.com/questions/157266/when-to-stop-using-a-hdd-what-rules-software-apply/157276#157276) contains a lot of tools you can use for that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error comes up at times when Windows has had problems writing its "hibernation state" information onto the hard drive.

This would, of course, be explained by the fact that Windows was probably still writing data when the laptop hit the ground. In addition, hard drives do not like being moved around much when they are operational (reading or writing) due to the mechanical pieces inside the drive (read heads and such) which can move around in an unwanted way.

If you don't make a habit of tossing the hard drive around while it's on, this one incident shouldn't be a problem, especially considering that laptop hard drives are usually built with protection mechanisms that stop the read heads and platters when they detect changing g-forces or simple vibration.

If you're really worried, simply run a disk-check tool from a Linux emergency-boot CD/DVD such as: http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/ to make sure your drive hasn't suffered any serious damage.

Just remember that Windows' built in drive-check is really just a file integrity checker and doesn't go deeper down and scan the true drive fitness.

Comment: I'd like to point out that Windows 7's `chkdsk` does do a physical scan of the disk, and at times is more accurate in checking whether a drive is damaged (in terms of bad sectors found) than previous versions. Otherwise your answer is flawless.

Comment: As I stated in the question, this laptop has no battery.  It was powered down completely before I removed it from the base station and started moving it.  +1 for the great info.