# Blue screen after Windows 7 login, "Driver Irql Not Less Or Equal"

Tags: windows-7, bsod

This occurs just after I log into Windows 7 Home Premium.

Does any body what this means and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: This program may help...http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Comment: Journeyman - I suggest it's not a duplicate since ben950's circumstances are different. He says bluescreen happens immediately after login, where as the linked-to question bluescreens happen randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a malfunctioning driver activated as it occurs after login, or do you experience randomness?

Please read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560244%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to troubleshoot your BSOD, try to see if Safe Mode works and check the Event Log.

If you can get there, please upload the dump file so we can analyze for you which driver did this.

---

**Edit:**

Not checking the crash dump is trying to fix a problem without knowing what the problem is.

So, you can try to remotely obtain the crash dump file, it is located at one of these two paths:

1. `C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP`
2. `C:\Windows\Minidump\*.DMP`

The best way would be to connect the hard drive to another computer...

---

**Edit 2:**

The driver that is crashing your computer multiple times is `mfehidk.sys`, from McAfee, your virus scanner.

```
SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M (1000007e)
This is a very common bugcheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem.

Probably caused by : mfehidk.sys ( mfehidk+188e9 )
```

If we list the module, we get:

```
fffff880`03ab2000 fffff880`03afba00   mfehidk  T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: mfehidk.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\mfehidk.sys
    Image name: mfehidk.sys
    Timestamp:        Fri Jul 31 23:59:58 2009 (4A73695E)
    CheckSum:         0004F637
    ImageSize:        00049A00
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
```

It's April 2011 and that driver dates back to July 2009, **that's horribly out of date** for a virus scanner.

If you can get into safe mode you can try to remove the virus scanner, if not you could attempt to rename `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\mfehidk.sys` so that the operating system should not load it anymore.

There are ony two dumps mentioning the `iastor.sys` driver, which is related to your hard disk. This makes sense as either the virus scanner driver or the hard disk driver is accessing memory in such way that the other one can't write to it, as a virus scanner scans files but this one seems to do it too early...

See how both dumps have problems reading or writing the memory:

```
ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx.
The memory could not be %s.

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)
Arg1: 00000000000007e1, memory referenced
Arg3: 0000000000000001, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff8800112a4ff, address which referenced memory
```

So, the steps to take are:

- **Prevent the virus scanner from loading**, with either safe mode or by renaming the driver.

  This will verify if the virus scanner is the culprit.
- If it's not the virus scanner, do a error scan on your memory and hard disk.

---

**Edit 3:**

As you are crashing on the `iastor.sys` only now, I've looked at its date.

```
fffff880`010ba000 fffff880`011d6000   iaStor    Fri Jun 05 03:53:40 2009 (4A287AA4)
```

If I look at mine I see this:

[image]

So, updating your Intel Rapid Storage Technology drivers might fix your issue.

Uninstall any Intel Matrix RAID and Intel Rapid Storage Technology drivers first if possible...

Comment: Or try Last known good config. Better bug check page here...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560129(v=VS.85).aspx... main page ...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff542347.aspx

Comment: sorry i am now experancing problems trying to login in safe mode. another blue screen that just poped up is system_service_exception. if and when it eventualy i will post log of erroe from event log

Comment: @Moab: Actually, the title mentions the bug check that does contain "Driver". Thanks for the other info!

Comment: @ben950: Try a repair from the installation medium, as it sounds random try Josh's answer. Do you remember if you have connected any devices to your computer lately or installed any software/drivers that might have done this? Updated the question with an alternative way to get to the dump file...

Comment: i managed to try and do a system restore but it still has the same problem. i have narrowed down the error message to iastor.sys is casing the problem. i think i might try a system repair to see if this works

Comment: i have found the logs but it wont let me upload the document to here and the logs are massive for me to ocpy paste

Comment: @ben950: Put it in a zip file, the size should decrease. Then use any upload site. For text, copy paste it to a site like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com)...

Comment: @ben950: No, you need to upload the dumps, not copy paste the text out of them. In a result your first link is unreadable and you seem to have copied the wrong link for the second one...

Comment: so like this http://www.speedyshare.com/files/27902148/minidumps.zip 
http://www.speedyshare.com/files/27901991/MEMORY.zip

Comment: @ben950: Yes, I've updated my post for the minidumps, now checking the other one.

Comment: @ben950: I can't open the MEMORY.DMP, but it's not necessary as the minidumps show the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much it was to do with mcaffee which i am in the process of geting rid of i dont no why i actualy left it there. once again thankyou

Comment: ok i have removed mcafee from the pc but it is still bringing up a blue screen when i boot normaly into windows any other suggestions? i have done a memory test and this passed with 0 problems

Comment: What errors is it showing now? Check your hard disk SMART status and run an error scan on it, see also: http://superuser.com/questions/157266/when-to-stop-using-a-hdd-what-rules-software-apply/157276#157276

Comment: i have not run an error scan on the harddrive and it has come back with 0 errors. do you want me to attach any more logs?

Comment: now i am getting the blue screen message system_service_exception Stop 0x0000003b

Comment: the instruction at 0xfd277048 referenced memory 0xfd13b498 the memory cannot be written

Comment: and another bluescreen that just flashed up is page_fault_in_nonpaged_area

Comment: Can't tell much about those blue-screens without dumps, try updating your drivers and disconnect any hardware that you don't need for proper operation.

Comment: what dumps do u need memory.dmp and mini dumps again?

Comment: @ben950: The latest, those that have the time that it occurred next to them.

Comment: here are the minidumps im just uploading the memory.dmp at the moment  http://www.speedyshare.com/files/27920874/minidump.zip

Comment: @ben950: Updated the bottom of my answer.

Comment: thanks and to find the new intel stuff i just go on there site ?

Comment: Yes, try to find the newest version of their drivers there.

Comment: ok. also what program of software do you use to read the dumps?

Comment: **WinDbg**, from the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551063(v=VS.85).aspx), I use `!analyze -v` to get a lot of information and `lm t` to get the timestamps for the drivers, `lm v` gvies a lot more information but takes a long time. [Make sure that you set your symbols right](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503).

Comment: Thanks My laptop seems to now be functioning without any blue screen once again thanks you

Answer (score 3):

This is likely a hardware problem. It is very difficult to determine because it is a generic-enough message that it could be any number of subsystem components - graphics, CPU, memory failure, hard disk or controller, etc.

**My first suggestion is to run [Memtest](http://www.memtest.org/)**, which will test the stability of the memory subsystem. Usually if you're able to get through this your CPU has a good chance of survival as well.

Next would be to see if Windows boots into Safe Mode, by hitting <kbd>F8</kbd> before Windows starts up (just before the "Loading Microsoft Windows" appears on bootup). If you are able to successfully get into Safe Mode, you can start trouble-shooting other hardware components by enabling / disabling or uninstalling / reinstalling drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Had this happen and diagnosed the problem for weeks. 
Eventually read a few posts in the darkest corners of the web which gave me some hope. 
Took my laptop apart, dusted it thoroughly, removed the very hard and dry thermal paste off the CPU, GPU and chipset and replaced with fresh paste. Booted, working, no more issues.

*Before doing the above I ran every benchmark and memory test I could find. 
Downgraded my video card driver to the standard windows driver, disabled network cards and anything else i did not use. 
Booted into safe mode etc... trying to determine where the problem lay. 
Checked the thermals on my laptop, looked good within specifications.
None of this helped though.*